# Does HashSet's containsAll() make comparison of collection sizes before checking elements?

Tags: java

Does `HashSet`'s `containsAll()` make comparison of collection sizes before checking elements?

Comment: What is ``java.util.containsAll``? Are you talking about the Collections? And what sense would it make to check any sizes in general? I could only see a reason when invoking it on a Set.

Comment: java.util.Set.containsAll()

Comment: @LaRRy. Why don't you look at the source code? It's freely available. and comes bundled with JDK.

Comment: I cannot find a source code. Seriously, If you could give me a link, then it would be the answer to this question.

Comment: @LaRRy. You have that in your `JDK` home folder. Are you using Windows? If yes, in the JDK home folder, find a zipped `src` file. That's the course code.

Comment: @LaRRy, I did a google search for "source to java.util.Set" and the first hit is the source code for java.util.Set: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/Set.java

Comment: And you need to specifically check the implementations, not the interface.  i.e. HashSet and TreeSet

Comment: @LaRRy the ez way to see the java source is to google `grepcode java.util.Collections`

Comment: @Brandon: Thats just the interface. Search for ``java.util.AbstractCollection``.

Comment: HashSet. And about the link - there are no source code, only needed arguments and exception, that can be thrown.

Comment: In terms of complexity it doesn't need to because, as seen in the source code, if the answer is `false` then numer of iterations in worst case will be the size of the smaller set

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`HashSet` extends `AbstractSet` which in turn extends `AbstractCollection` (which defines the `containsAll` method). You can find the source of `AbstractCollection` [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/AbstractCollection.java). You will find that `containsAll` ([line 292](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/AbstractCollection.java#292)) is implemented as:

```
public boolean containsAll(Collection<?> c) {
    Iterator<?> e = c.iterator();
    while (e.hasNext())
        if (!contains(e.next()))
            return false;
    return true;
}
```

So no, no comparison of collection sizes is made.